# Specific Principle branch to define inverse cosine

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

[image: Question]

Really have no idea what to do. I have tried letting z = 0 = (e^iz + e^-iz)/2i but all that does is cos z = pi/2. Doesn't give me a formula for cos^-1 z and doesn't help with part (b).

Comment: Take a look at this question , it was answered today: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652439/solve-cosz-frac34-fraci4/652579#652579

Comment: Use **two** letters: $w=(\exp(iz)+\exp(-iz))/2$. An now $z=$...

Comment: why cant i see your answer

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\cos z = w$.  We will invert $w = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}z}+\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}z}}{2}$.  Substitute $x$ for $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}z}$ (and $\frac{1}{x}$ for $\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}z}$).  Solve for $x$.  Unsubstitute and finish solving for $z$.  This is a formula that converts values of $w$ into values of $z$, which means it does the job of $\cos^{-1}$.

Comment: So I get x = w +(w^2 - 1)^1/2. Do I then substitute this back into the original w?

Comment: @Omar: "Unsubstitute and finish solving for z."